# IE 8 Incorrectly Positioning 960 Grid

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, 960.gs

I have the below html & class structure. It displays as expected in Firefox, but in IE 8 the `rt-col` is pushed to the following row. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
...
...
<div id="main" class="container_12">
  <div id="lt-col" class="grid_8">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="rt-col" class="grid_4">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS pertaining to the containers & grids are below:

```
#main:after, #lt-col:after, #rt-col:after { 
   content: "."; 
   height: 0; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   clear: both; 
} 

#main { 
   width: 960px; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a doctype set? without it rendering in IE defaults to Quirks mode and tends to mess up rendering badly.

Comment: Could you post some css as well if you're using any besides the 960 stuff.

Comment: @scunliffe: Yes, I've set the doctype; see edits above. @Matijs: I've edited my original post to include the css that pertains to the containers and grids. The other css I excluded since it relates to typography, background, etc...

Comment: testing the given code with a grid css too is not reproducing the described error in IE8, (two columns are sitting nicely side by side) so I think there must be something else in your other CSS's which are conflicting, any way you can reproduce a minimal and the whole code in JSBin or something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to build a left and right column grid:

You need to define an explicit width for each column. Currently, you have none. And since you're using the "clear: both;" attribute and value on both columns, they'll simply display as rows.

Add this to your CSS (or some variation of widths) and your rows will turn to columns:

```
    #lt-col {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
    }
    #rt-col {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: You're right I am trying to build a left and right column. While I do understand your solution, I'm unclear as to why I need to set the width; doesn't `grid_*` set the width? Also, by `clear:both` isn't that clearing *inside* the div and not the div itself?

Comment: You didn't include the CSS for the classes "grid_8" and "grid_4," so I'm not able to see if they're setting the width or not. And you might be misunderstanding the purpose of the "clear" attribute and its values: When applying the "clear" attribute to an element, you prohibit other elements from floating either left or right of it.

Answer (score 0):

@clairesuzy I think the issue lies on the styling that is applied. There is some style that is adding a padding to either the main div or the rt-col and lt-col div

this can easily be sorted by using the below code to start with

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_8">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
  ...
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

this above will work out of the box irrespective of any styling...

then do this and ensure there is no padding

```
<div id="main">

    <div class="container_12">

        <div class="grid_8">
            <div id="lt-col">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
            <div id="rt-col">...</div>
        </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

simplified version of what you wish to do

Comment: if further issue persists, please post a link to the place where this code is live, I shall surely help you further - cheers!